# Are all instances of European quantitative easing in the last 50 years, publicaly documented?

Tags: data-request, quantitative-easing, transparency

Are all instances of legal, **ex nihilo**, quantitative easing (QE) within Europe, publically documented for the past 50 years, or is that process/data obfuscated?

If yes, is there a `json/text/csv/...` file with the respective:

1. dates
2. quantity
3. Specification of the central bank that issued it?

Comment: do you mean money creation or do you mean quantitative easing? please choose one

Comment: It seems like you're just asking for a list of QE events. I think you should ask for "instances of QE" instead of "instances of money creation (by means of QE)" because the second one makes us guess whether you just meant QE or not.

Comment: what is the difference between "ex nihilo QE" and QE? and the difference between "legal QE" and QE? are you interested in whether the ECB is breaking the law?

Comment: I am not aware of any differences between those, though this prevents the answers from being polluted with options I may not be aware of. *Legal* was a relic from the *money creation* aspect in the original question. E.g.: people may have printed money illegally, which may be seen by some as a form of illegal *money creation*. I am not interested in that activity in this question. Similarly, QE may also involve some other activities that I am not aware of. So in essence, the question is over-constrained. No, this question assumes ECB adheres to the law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single centralized dataset recording them all one file. This being said such data are being kept by separate monetary authorities.

QE definition by ECB is a bit different than the definition used by Fed. I assume since you are interested in Europe  you want to use ECB definition. Following, [ECB's (2021)](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/ecb/educational/explainers/show-me/html/app_infographic.en.html) QE is simply defined as:

> Asset purchases, also known as quantitative easing or QE

Hence, following ECB's definition you can find list of ECB's QE [here](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/implement/app/html/index.en.html). The text file at the link contains dates and quantities of money used for the asset purchase. To my best knowledge ECB does not make distinction between itself and national central banks that are members of the Economic and Monetary Union when it comes to APP. Hence, all of these asset purchases can be consider as being part of ECB's QE.  National central banks such as Dutch DNB or Irish CBI just link bank to ECB's data ([example](https://www.centralbank.ie/monetary-policy/policy-implementation/asset-purchase-programmes)).

Also, in recent modern history asset purchases were generally not used by monetary policy. These data show all APP's since 1998 when ECB was set up for European Monetary Union. When it comes to national central banks outside EMU or prior 1998 you have to check individual central bank data. There are too many countries to give link to every single national central bank dataset so I will just give an example for UK (Bank of England asset purchases are documented [here](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/search#?cludoquery=asset%20purchase%20facility&cludopage=1&cludorefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bankofengland.co.uk%2F&cludorefpt=Home%20%7C%20Bank%20of%20England&cludorefact=asset%20purchase%20&cludorefaci=1&cludoinputtype=standard)). Most, if not all European central banks have similar reports on their website you have to check them for non-EMU countries one by one. Using these you should be able to find all instances of such programmes except for former soviet republics where central bank data might be missing prior the fall of communist regimes (however it is questionable if any policy during those times would qualify due to lack of capital & financial markets in USSR).

Here is also graph of various ECB QE programmes with dates:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, explanation and links to the related documents. Based on [this definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/asset.asp), I find it a bit difficult to understand the meaning of PSPP, CBPP3, CSPP and ABSPP in context of the question. I think what I would like to ask: are these asset purchases all performed using money created `ex nihilo`? And if not, is it still possible from the sources you referred to distinguish which parts of those purchases are performed using money created ex nihilo, or not?

Comment: @a.t. yes any asset purchase of central bank is done by ex nihilo money creation. Central banks do not purchase assets with pre-existing money. Any time they purchase an asset they create money ex nihilo (outside of countries that have problem with currency substitution, but I do not believe there is any european country currently having that issue).